# Image size zero when src'd as blob-url but not when src'd as data-url

Tags: image-processing, blob, clojurescript

I have a image blob that I want the height and width of, so I create a blob url, set the src of an image object to it, and then get the height and width of the image object.

```
(let [window-url (or (-> js/window .-URL)
                       (-> js/window .-webkitURL))
        blob-url (window-url.createObjectURL blob)
        image (js/Image.)]
    (set! (.-src image) blob-url)
    (prn "image height" (.-height image))
    (prn "image width " (.-width image))
      )
```

But the result I get is:

image height 0
image width 0

But obviously the image doesn't have a 0 height and width, which I've already verified by displaying the image on the document through its data-url (which I then convert into the blob referred above like `(js/Blob. [data-url])`). So why is the blob's height and width zero if the corresponding data-url does show on the document?

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the properties `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` of the image instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image#Usage_note

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587859/set-onload-image-fn-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can only get the `height/width` after the image has been "loaded" so you need to attach an `onload` event handler. Using a blob URL does not change that restriction.

Probably something like this, I didn't test it though.

```clj
(let [window-url (or (-> js/window .-URL)
                     (-> js/window .-webkitURL))
      blob-url (.createObjectURL window-url blob)
      image (js/Image.)]
  (set! (.-onload image)
    (fn [e]
      (prn "image height" (.-height image))
      (prn "image width " (.-width image))))
  (set! (.-src image) blob-url))
```

Comment: Nothing prints when I put the print statements in the onload function. Why might this be?

Comment: Maybe it fails to load? Try adding an `onerror` event handler and see what that says.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587859/set-onload-image-fn-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we do it in our codebase. As Thomas Heller pointed out, you need to load the image in order to get proper image metadata.

```
(defn with-image-data
  "Asynchronously load an image `file` in a FileReader, then call the `callback`
  fn with a proper Image object"
  [file callback]
  (let [reader (js/FileReader.)
        img    (js/Image.)]
    (set! (.-onload reader) #(set! (.-src img) (.-result reader)))
    (set! (.-onerror reader) #(js/console.error %))
    (set! (.-onload img) (fn [_] (callback img)))
    (.readAsDataURL reader file)
    nil))
```

Comment: Nothing prints when I put the print statements in the onload function. Why might this be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587859/set-onload-image-fn-not-working\